# Strange Bug with User Input and Switch Statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
public class VoteTUIView {

    VoteMachine voteMachine;

    public VoteTUIView(VoteMachine voteMachine) {
        this.voteMachine = voteMachine;
        this.start();

    }

    public static String errorMissingVariable = "This command needs an variable";
    public static String errorPartyNoneExistant = "This party does not exist";
    public static String errorAddImpossible = "You can't add something to that";
    public static String help = "Seriously? You need help? You look like a smart boy/girl, you can figure this out yourself. I believe in you! ";


    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Please insert a command: (VOTE [party], ADD PARTY [party], VOTES, PARTIES, EXIT, and HELP) ");
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(inputScanner.hasNextLine()){
            String inputCommand = inputScanner.next();
            switch (inputCommand){
                case "VOTE": {
                    if(inputScanner.hasNext()){
                        String inputCommand2 = inputScanner.next();
                        if(voteMachine.getParties().getParties().contains(inputCommand2)){
                            voteMachine.vote(inputCommand2);
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println(errorPartyNoneExistant);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(errorMissingVariable);
                    }
                }
                case "ADD": {
                    if(inputScanner.next().equals("PARTY")) {
                        if(inputScanner.hasNext()) {
                            voteMachine.addParty(inputScanner.next());
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println(errorMissingVariable);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        showError(errorAddImpossible);
                    }
                }
                case "VOTES": {
                    showVotes(voteMachine.getVotes().getVoteList());
                }
                case "PARTIES": {
                    showParties(voteMachine.getParties().getParties());
                }
                case "EXIT": {
                    break;
                }
                case "HELP": {
                    System.out.println(help);
                }
                default: {
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nPlease insert a command: (VOTE [party], ADD PARTY [party], VOTES, PARTIES, EXIT, and HELP) ");
        }
    }

    public void showVotes(Map<String, Integer> voteList) {
        int i = 1;
        for(String partyName : voteList.keySet()){
            System.out.println(i+": "+partyName+" has obtained "+voteList.get(partyName)+" votes.");
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void showParties(List<String> partyList) {
        int i = 1;
        for(String partyName : partyList){
            System.out.println(i+": "+partyName);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void showError(String error) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + error);
    }        
}
```

I am fighting with a strange bug. The program reads the user input and determines which action to take with a switch but often, multiple cases in the switch are triggered when they clearly shouldn't be. It's driving me mad. Does anybody know why it does that?

```
Please insert a command: (VOTE [party], ADD PARTY [party], VOTES, PARTIES, EXIT, and HELP)   
ADD PARTY DemoCant's  
1: DemoCant's

Please insert a command: (VOTE [party], ADD PARTY [party], VOTES, PARTIES, EXIT, and HELP)   
ADD PARTY RepublicRats  
1: DemoCant's  
2: RepublicRats

Please insert a command: (VOTE [party], ADD PARTY [party], VOTES, PARTIES, EXIT, and HELP)   
VOTE DemoCant's  
VOTE DemoCant's 
Error: You can't add something to that  
1: DemoCant's has obtained 1 votes.  
1: DemoCant's  
2: RepublicRats
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `break` statements on almost all `switch` cases so the code just falls though to the next case. See the section on fall though in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
case "VOTE": {
    ....
    break;
} 
.....
```

Answer (score 3):

The `case`s in a `switch` statement fall through, and continue executing the next `case`. If you don't want your `case` to fall through, add a `break;` statement and the end of the `case`. E.g.:

```
switch (inputCommand){
    case "VOTE":
        // code for voting
        break;
    case "ADD": {
        // code for adding
        break;
    // etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am fighting with a strange bug.

Which is why you would have used your debugger before asking a question.

> The program reads the user input and determines which action to take with a switch but often, multiple cases in the switch are triggered when they clearly shouldn't be.

since there is no `break;` or `return;` there is no reason to break out of the switch.

Note: Java, C, C++, C# all do this.

> It's driving me mad. Does anybody know why it does that?

Because that is what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing break statement. Without a break statement it is an expected behavior. 
You can do more reading about this here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

add the `break` statement after each `Case`

If you don't add a `break` statement the code flow will go into the next case until all the case ends or till a `break` is encountered